# Calculate commission with amount threshold

Tags: c#

I have different schemas for different kind of commission over the sales. From 0 to 10.000€ its pay a commission of 2%, from 10.001 to 20.000 the commission is 2.5%, 20.001 to 30.000 is payee a commission of 3% and so until the commission is 5% or more. The threshold amount and the commission is taken from the database in a list. The problem is that I have to take on account the sales since the beginning of the year to achieve the given threshold but only calculated the commission for the sale of the current month. For instance if the sales in a given month is 30.000 and the cumulated sales from the beginning of the year is 8.000, the calculation is: 2.000 at 2%, 10.000 at 2.5 %, 10.000 at 3% and 8.000 at 3.5% with a result of 870. This is the code that I have but don’t work fine. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
            foreach (var bound in fxCollection)
            {
                if (antAmount < bound.FinalAmount)
                {
                    if (antAmount >= bound.InitialAmount && antAmount <= bound.FinalAmount)
                    {
                        if (totalAmount > bound.FinalAmount)
                        {
                            totalAmountCardSchema = totalPeriod - (bound.FinalAmount.Value - antAmount);
                            totalCommission += (bound.FinalAmount.Value - antAmount) * (bound.Commission / 100);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            totalCommission += totalPeriod * (bound.Commission / 100);
                            totalCommission = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ((bound.FinalAmount - bound.InitialAmount) < totalAmountCardSchema)
                        {
                            if (index == count) //last loop
                            {
                                totalCommission += totalAmountCardSchema * (bound.Commission / 100);
                                totalAmountCardSchema = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                totalCommission += (bound.FinalAmount.Value - bound.InitialAmount.Value) * (bound.Commission / 100);
                                totalAmountCardSchema = totalAmountCardSchema - (bound.FinalAmount.Value - bound.InitialAmount.Value);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (totalAmountCardSchema > 0)
                        {
                            totalCommission += totalAmountCardSchema * (bound.Commission / 100);
                            totalAmountCardSchema = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                index++;
                var valueInvoiceLine = totalCommission;
```

To clarify:
Yes, this is the point. In the example is fine. To clarify, the sales from 1th of January until 31th May was 8.000 and the sales in one month was 30.000. I put this example because I want loop in several band for calculate the commission of the month but for achieve the first band to calculate the initial band in this month I have to add the sales since the first day of the year. In the example the first band is from 0 to 10.000 but I have to add the sales for the first day of the year (8.000) and then of the sales of the month (30.000), I have to take only 2.000 in the first band, in the second band I have to take 10.000, in the third band I have to take another 10.000 and in the fourth band I have to take the rest (8.000). Sorry if it’s not very clear. I hope that you understand. Thanks you so much.

Comment: Well, as it is now it's difficult to understand what rules should be applied and when. Could you please clarify it.

Comment: Agreed. In your sample, you mention year-to-date (cumulative) of 8, which is below 30 for the month. This doesn't make sense unless monthly has not yet been added to cumulative. Please state your commission logic in plain words and we can help with the coding.

Comment: I tried to clarify. Thanks Fabjan and Shannon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
            decimal totalAmount = 35;
            decimal commission = 0.0M;
            decimal commissionAmount = 0.0M;

            Dictionary<decimal,decimal> commissions = new Dictionary<decimal,decimal>() {
                { 0, .02M}, ///2%
                { 10, .005M}, //2.5%
                { 20, .005M}, //3.0%
                { 30, .005M}, //3.5%
                { 40, .005M}, //4.0%
                { 50, .005M}, //4.5%
                { 60, .005M}, //5.0%
            };

            foreach (decimal key in commissions.Keys)
            {
                if (totalAmount > key)
                {
                    commissionAmount = totalAmount - key;
                }
                else
                {
                    commissionAmount = totalAmount - key < 0 ? 0 : totalAmount - key;
                }
                commission += commissionAmount * commissions[key];
            }
```

Comment: Jdweng: Thanks for the answer but I have to take the former sales for calculate the commission in the mont. In your example if the former sales are 8, in the first band (2%) I only have to calculate 10-8 *2% and then follow with 33 in the rest of the band.

Comment: Did you check the answer?  I'm doing the calculation more efficiently for graduated commission.  I'm doing 2% of everything, then .5% of everything above 10, then another .5% of everything above 20, then another .5% above 30.  The results is the same.

Comment: Yes, your solution is more efficiently that mine. The only that I need, because I can't is that you take on account the sales from the previous months to begin to calculate the commission. For instance if the sales of the previous month are 35.000 and the sales of the current month are 10.000, I have to calculate 5.000 in the band between 30-40.000 at 3.5% and the other 5.000 in the band of 40-50.000 at 4%. Please, let me know how I can do this. Thanks you so much.

Comment: You need to keep track of the amount already paid in commission.  You calculate each month the commission from the 1st of of the year and then subtract the amount previously paid to get the current month commission.